# Динамически добавить разметку MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Возникла необходимость динамически добавлять на страницу несложную `html` разметку - (2 текстового поля). Нашел статью где говориться, что подобные действия лучше всего производить с помощью `Ajax` дабы не перезагружать страницу. Т.к. использую MVC то стартовую разметку добавлял через шаблон представления `Create` по модели `New_summary`. Модель :

```
public sealed class New_summary
{
    [Display(Name = "Личные данные")]
    public PrivateData Sum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Мои навыки")]
    public Skill Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Класс `Skill` :

```
public class Skill
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ExpirienceYear { get; set; }
}
```

Разметка :

```
<div>
<h5>Добавьте ключевые навыки и опыт работы (лет)</h5>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Skills, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         <div class="skills">
             @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Skills.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Skills.ExpirienceYear, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                <div id="add_scill"></div>
         </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
        <input type="button" value="Добавить навык" onclick="AddItem()" />
        <script>
            function AddItem()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/User/add_skill",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (result) {
                        var domElement = $(result);
                        $('#add_scill').append(domElement);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

И сам контроллер к которому обращается JS :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult add_skill()
 {
     Skill skill = new Skill();
     return View("skills", skill);
 }
```

Судя по брейкпоинтам - на контроллер приложение даже не попадает, а в консоле браузера выдает - ошибку сервера №500 :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Может допустил совсем глупую ошибку, тк JS код пишу 2 раз в жизни. Также непонятно пока - а как в контроллер попадет коллекция `Skill` если в `New_summary` не `IEnumerable<Skill>` а просто свойство `Skill`, но это уже другой вопрос. Помагите разобраться с динамической разметкой.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     url: "/User/add_skill",
>     dataType: "html",
>     success: function (result) {
>         var domElement = $(result);
>         $('#add_scill').append(domElement);
>     }
> });
> ```

А сами данные ты не посылаешь.

Comment: не понял. в контроллер add_skill ничего и не приходит

Comment: Ты посылаешь пустой запрос - вполне логично, что в метод приходить нечему.

Comment: так туда и недолжно ничего приходить. или... ?

Comment: Тогда поля ввода текста тебе зачем, если не должно?

Comment: данные из полей ввода (эти и все остальные) попадают в другой контролер который записывает их в БД. Контроллер `add_skill` должен просто добавить пустую форму для данных.

Comment: Тогда почему post, а не get?

Comment: https://hellomvc.blogspot.ru/2011/04/ajax-aspnet-mvc.html    -тут прочитал

Comment: даже если поставить GET то в контроллер программа приходит но видимо что то не правильно возвращает.